# Using skimage reader

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image

Some of my code uses skimage to read tiff images and process them, however, when trying to use the reader I get the following error:

C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/workflow/Lib/site-packages\skimage\external\tifffile\tifffile.py in _process_tags(self)

2196                     except KeyError:
   2197                         raise ValueError("%s.value (%s) not supported" %
-> 2198                                          (name, tags[name].value))
   2199             elif default is not None:
   2200                 setattr(self, name, validate[default] if validate else default)

ValueError: fill_order.value (0) not supported

As the error seems to be linked to the format of the tiff images I have tried making sure they have no padding etc but I am very new to processing images and am not sure if I am trying the right things

Comment: Looks like you have an invalid TIFF file. The FillOrder tag can have values 1 or 2.

Comment: Is this something I can easily fix, I have the original .cif files and extracted the tiffs myself.